# Array in route parameter cause "Expected to not repeat" warning

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

When I try to create a `router-link` with an array as parameter, the link works but I get the following warning :

> missing param for named route "start-run": Expected "files" to not repeat, but received `["aaa"]`

**router.js**

```
...
{
  path: '/start-run/:config?/:files?',
  name: 'start-run',
  component: StartRun,
  props: true
},
...
```

**file.vue**

```
...
<router-link :to="{name: 'start-run', params: { config: 'test', files: ['aaa'] }}">...</router-link>
...
```

I didn't find documentation to fix this warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error message comes from `path-to-regexp` version 1.7.0, which is used by Vue Router:

https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/blob/v1.7.0/index.js#L185

The problem is that an array is treated as multiple values but the parameter in your path does not support multiple values.

It is unclear what you are trying to achieve by passing an array to `files`. The route path you've defined uses a `?` suffix for `:files?`, which makes it optional but doesn't allow for an array. Perhaps you meant `:files*` or `:files+` instead? Or maybe you just want to pass the first item in the array?

Comment: I assumed that `?` was for any optional parameter, the one I need is `:files*`. In my opinion the usage of `*` is confusing with [the wildcard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#catch-all-404-not-found-route).

Comment: @Opsse The syntax is based on RegExp modifiers. So `?` means 0 or 1 whereas `*` means 0 or more. Later versions of `path-to-regexp` have removed support for using `*` as a wildcard because it was causing confusion and ambiguity.